# Google login integrated and 2FA

Tags: authentication, google

this is a quick question, but I really want to know this for sure:

If I integrate an option in my site which allows users to log in with their Google account, should I **also** provide them a function to use a second factor of authentication in my page or should  I let Google handle this topic with users Google account?

Comment: The correct answer depends on what you're trying to protect yourself and your users from, and the hassle you're willing to accept and put on your users by adding "extra security".

Comment: Yes, but I mean, adding 2FA should not be necessary extra security, as people who want to use it, has it enabled in their Google account configuration. Am I wrong?

Comment: Google accounts may choose to "never ask again" for a 2FA authentication on a certain device, so even if 2FA is enabled, it doesn't need to be "really" active. If you need to protect yourself from a compromised google account, you need to perform "some" step of authentication on your behalf. This could be implemented by adding and enforcing 2FA on your website, but will bring some hassle to your users.

Comment: Sweet, thank you, now I got it. Write it down as an answer so I can set it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google accounts may choose to "never ask again" for a 2FA authentication on a "trusted" device, so even if 2FA is enabled for an account, it doesn't need to be "that" much active as your security policy assumes from 2FA.

So if you need to protect yourself from a compromised Google account (even one using Google's 2FA), you'll need to perform "some" extra step of authentication on your behalf. This could be implemented by adding and enforcing your own 2FA on your website, but doing so can also bring some hassle or confusion to your users.